# Rails upgradation from 3.2.x to 4.0.3 with Ruby 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

#### models/user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :username, :login
end
```

#### models/post.rb

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :user

  attr_accessible :user_id, :description, :title
end
```

#### models/comment.rb

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :user

  attr_accessible :body, :user_id
end
```

I have installed 'strong_parameters'. And trying to make out with it. Can any one please guide me for model and controller code for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `attr_accessible` from models.

And in the controller, lets take the example of `PostsController`, create a private method `post_params` where you will define accessible attributes of Post model

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

    def update
        @post = Post.find(params[:id])
        if @post.update(post_params)
            redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully updated.'
        else
            render "edit"
        end
    end

    private

    def post_params
        params.require(:post).permit(:user_id, :description, :title)
    end

end
```